# How to fetch data from database using nested many to many relationships in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm working on Laravel `Access Control Level (ACL)` system. where is table contains some `many to many` to relationship. `User` table has many to many `belongsToMany` with `Role` Table and inversely many to many `Role` has `belongsToMany` with `User` table.Again, `Role` table has many to many `belongsToMany` relationship with `Permission` table and inversely `Permission` has many to many `belongsToMany` with `Role` table.

> I want to run a query from user table which is fetch the all permissions of a role. this role is assigned to current user through roles table.

Here is my code sample.

**User Model**

```
 public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongstoMany(Role::class);
}
```

**Role Model**

```
 public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
}

public function permissions()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Permission::class);
}
```

**Permission Table**

```
 public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class);
}
```

I've tried this query using egar loading...

```
public function hasPermission($permission)
{
   if($this->roles()->with('permissions')->get()->pluck('permissions'))
   {
    return true;
   }
   return false;
}
```

But it always `return false`.

Comment: did you try to `dd( $this->roles()->with('permissions')->get() )`? Also, in the same method, you never use the `$permission` variable

Comment: yes, it's shows a collections

Comment: Is it empty collection? If there are roles, can you inspect if those roles have any permissions? Or add the value of `dd()` into the question

Comment: `$data=Auth::user()->roles()->with('permissions')->get()->pluck('permissions');` this return a collections. but now if i want to add a where condition how can i do that ?

Comment: You can filter out the result collection with `filter()` [method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-filter).

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to check if one of the roles has given permission.

One example, add `hasPermission` method to `User.php` model

```
public function hasPermission($permission = '') {
  if ( empty($permisison) ) {
     return false;
  }

  /*
    Find all user roles that have given permission
  */
  $rolesWithPermission = $this
                          ->roles()
                            ->whereHas('permissions', function($query) use ($permission) {
                              $query->where('name', $permission);
                            })
                          ->get();

  /*
    If there is at least one role with given permission,
    user has permission
  */
  return $rolesWithPermission->count() > 0;
}
```

Or you can do one query with multiple joins between `users`, `roles` and `permissions`, and filter out the result with `where('permissions.name', '=', $permission)`